# file exist in Document folder but not for Xcode

Tags: iphone, file-manager

I have a strange problem, this code check if a file exist inside document folder:

```
- (BOOL) checkIfFileExist:(NSString *)path {    

    NSArray *documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileDaControllere = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:path];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileDaControllere]) {
        NSLog(@"exist");
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"not exist");
        return NO;
    }
}
```

the problem is that I get alway file not exist while the file exist (in this case the path is Style.css)! where is the mistake? 
The path seems to be correct:

Path: /Users/kikko/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/38161AFA-2740-4BE2-9EC4-C5C6B317D270/Documents/Style.css

Here you can see the path on xcode and real path

http://www.allmyapp.net/wp-content/iFormulario/1.png

http://www.allmyapp.net/wp-content/iFormulario/2.png

Comment: 1- are you sure file is in the document directory? did you copy/create there?
2- Check the file name, its case sensitive Style.css or style.css

Comment: have you try to test on **real** device as well? the simulator has no absolute right to access the Mac filesystem, including the Application's Documents folder, it can cause a little headache in spite of the file is really there and on the **real** device there is no problem to access it.

Comment: @holex I've used the code above in many of my apps and they all work perfectly on simulator with on exception that most mac's file systems aren't case sensitive where the one on iOS is.

Comment: @rckoenes, you were lucky. I never use the simulator, I'd experienced many difference between the behaviour of the `NSFileManager` class, so I simply don't trust the simulator, and I never use it... (and you also cannot reach many services in the simulator), and I'll never recommend to use it to anybody.

Comment: @holex, true some things will not work (camera, telephony,...). But it's fast to test UI and simple tasks. I always test on the device to check for if it works. After all it a simulator not an emulator ;) i've never had any really problems with `NSFilemanager`.

Comment: @rckoenes, I stopped to use it when I stared to experience the problems with the `NSFileManager` on the simulator. I have a pretty good application which loads images from the `Documents` library, and it crashes with _no permission_ error on the simulator, however, on the real device everything is working like a charm... but there were another issue with the `UITableCellView` on the simulator, it didn't work but on the real device it was perfect. you mentioned it is fast, the reliability is much more important for me, than the speed. :D so, the simulator is useless for me. it's my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved this issue, the strange think is that I don't know how I solved it, 
the first problem is that I pass to checkIfFifFileExist the absolute path while I need to pass it relative path, and the the function trasform it to absolute path (my big big error), after this I think the problem is the use of "/", I delete all and rewrite all the code and I doing some test.

I copy folder from bundle:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *folderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/icone"];
NSString *iconePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/icone"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:folderPath toPath:iconePath error:nil];
```

Then I make the path of my image in this way:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *imagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.objMateria.iconaMateria];
```

and now the file exist, a strange thing is that if:

```
self.objMateria.iconaMateria = /icona/Home/fisica.png
```

or

```
self.objMateria.iconaMateria = icona/Home/fisica.png
```

nothing change, I see the image, while I think that one of this has a wrong path...

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the fact that you just append the file without with check if there is a path delimitor:

```
NSString *fileDaControllere = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:path];
```

Thus you would become something like `../DocumentsStyle.css` but it should be `../Documents/Style.css`.

[`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) has a special method for appending path components [`stringByAppendingPathComponent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathComponent_)

```
NSString *fileDaControllere = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
```

Comment: thank you, I try in this method but is the same, file not exist while obviusly the file exist (i see it on documents directory)

Comment: Add a `NSLog` where you print out the `fileDaControllere` and check the path is correct.

Comment: Then test it on a real device as holex said there could be something wrong with `NSFileManager`.

Comment: I try also on device but nothing, I upload the path on simulator and on device, so you can see the path that I take with xcode and the real path

Comment: Can you make use that either the `icone` or the `Home` directory does not have a space behind it?

Comment: no one has space behind it, I check now, if I try to put my icon on bundle directory and I call the image only with icon/Home/image.png all work!